# Javascript: how to change <a> tag's color when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I run this code and press **black** button, every text changes their color to white, except `<a>` tag. 

I already selected entire body tag with `document.querySelector('body')`, but the link appears to be **blue**.

How can I select `<a>` tag independently and change its color to **white**?

Also, why `<a>` tag does not get effected by *javascript* code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <li>Hi!</li>
    <input type="button" value="night" onclick="
      document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'white';">
    <input type="button" value="day" onclick="
      document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'black';
      ">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
      <a href="https://google.com">link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add style code.

```
  <style>
   a{
     color: inherit;
   } 
  </style>
```

It gets the same color as the color in its top node (body).

Good Luck

Comment: Exactly. simples as this. the best answer. don't complicate.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName('a')`

And then you'd have to loop through them all and set their style.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('a').style.color = 'white';` tried this, but the link is still blue.

Comment: Yeah, that gives you an array of 'a'-tags, so you have to loop through them, like I said, or if you only have one `document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color = 'white';`.

Answer (score 0):

If not specific styles are applied to an `<a>` tag, it will have this blue color by deafult given by the browser.

The first thing you can do is give the tag an id `<a id="link" href="https://google.com">link</a>`, and change its color property through javascript with `document.getElementById('link').style.color = 'white'`. That way you'll only change the tags with that specific id.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <li>Hi!</li>
    <input type="button" value="night" onclick="
      document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'white';
      document.getElementById('link').style.color = 'white';
    ">
    <input type="button" value="day" onclick="
      document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'black';
      ">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
      <a id="link" href="https://google.com">link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to change all `<a>` tags in your html, you can add `<style>` in your `<head>`to make all `<a>` tags inherit css properties from the parent. So that it inherits, you'll have to give the parent () a color value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
       body {
           color: black;
       }
       a {
          color: inherit;
       } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <li>Hi!</li>
    <input type="button" value="night" onclick="
      document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'white';
    ">
    <input type="button" value="day" onclick="
      document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      document.querySelector('body').style.color = 'black';
      ">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
      <a id="link" href="https://google.com">link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to select `<a>` by its tag name instead of making an id?

Comment: What if there is more than one `<a>` element?

Comment: This depends in each case. If you want to change all ```<a>```tags the same way, you can select it by tag name, like @D.Pardal suggests in his answer. Otherwise if you want to change a specific tag, you can select it by id like I did.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because of how inheritance works in CSS. The browser styles the `<a>` tag as blue, and because of that, it doesn't inherit `color` from its ancestors.

I would recommend to set a class in your `<body>` element, and then use CSS to style it differently with/without the class, like this:

```css
body.dark {
  background-color: black;
}

body.dark,
body.dark a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <li>Hi!</li>
    <input type="button" value="night" onclick="document.body.classList.add('dark')">
    <input type="button" value="day" onclick="document.body.classList.remove('dark')">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
      <a href="https://google.com">link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
a:visited {
           color:orange
}
```